Android Studio I randomly get white screen when starting app
There are various other questions about white screens with Android Studio but I didn't see one that answered my question. I get a white screen randomly after the app logo when running an AVD. The only ways I've found to fix it are to wipe the AVD or delete the AVD and create a new one. Sometimes this problem happens after 1-2 runs, and sometimes I get as many as 6-7 runs. Never more than that.
I know the app is otherwise running okay because I'm able to click through where I know buttons are, and my print statements show in the console. I'm able to keep moving the ball down the field with frequent AVD recreates, but it's annoying.
This started only ~2-3 months ago. I have it happen on two different Windows 11 installs. I'm running Koala, but it started several versions before that.
What other info would you like?

Can you [edit] your question to include an image of the screen?

Thanks - yes, I will when it happens next. I know there's not much to go on here. I just installed the latest Flutter patch, and it's not happened in the last 8-10 runs.

I'm going to close this for now because of course it stopped failing after I posted this. Maybe the Flutter update did the trick.
